# Swift - how to apply resize images inside scrollview

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I have a following scrollview code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

var imageArray = [UIImage(named: "mainScrollView1"), UIImage(named: "mainScrollView2"), UIImage(named: "mainScrollView3"),]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    configurePageControl()

    scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.delegate = self

    for var i = 0; i < imageArray.count; i++  {

        if i == 0 {

            var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, 160))
            imageView.image = imageArray[i]
            scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

        } else {

            var float: CGFloat = CGFloat(i)
            var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * float, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, 160))
            imageView.image = imageArray[i]
            scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

        }
    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*3, scrollView.frame.size.height)

}

func configurePageControl() {

    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = 3
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
    self.pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.view.addSubview(pageControl)

}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
}
```

}

the problem is that images inside scroll a static ones, they do not change their size for different screen sizes and because of that it looks like this

[image]

as you see first image do not expands to fill whole screen width and because of this part of second image can be seen

How can this be fixed ?

Comment: set the contentSize in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: I try to call this again in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` `scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*3, scrollView.frame.size.height)` but it doesn't help, images stays the same. It seems that it has to be done in different way ?

Comment: not just scrollview but you need to set a width of image/page all in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update the image size after the view layout all subviews. You should do that in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Something like this:

```
var imageArray = [UIImage(named: "mainScrollView1"), UIImage(named: "mainScrollView2"), UIImage(named: "mainScrollView3"),]
var imageViews:[UIImageView] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configurePageControl()

    scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.delegate = self

    for image in imageArray {
        var imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        imageViews.append(imageView)
    }
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    for (index,imageView) in imageViews.enumerate() {
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(index)*scrollView.frame.size.width, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, 160)
    }
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*3, scrollView.frame.size.height)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! unfortunately code doesn't work, there is a problem with enumeration. Anyway I try to understand the code and I dont get why is there second array of imageViews ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have one array with images and second one with imageViews. You need to keep reference to the created imageViews so you can resize them after the view did layout subviews.

Comment: That makes more sense, thanks! But now it complains about `binary operator * cannot be applied to Int and CGFloat`

Comment: You have to use CGFloat(index)